# BigQuery - How to instantiate BigQueryTemplate without env variables? getting The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-oauth, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I'm trying to instantiate BigQueryTemplate without the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Steps tried:

1. Implemented `CredentialsSupplier` by instantiating `Credentials` and setting location to service account json file.
2. Instantiated Bean `BigQuery` using `BigQueryOptions::newBuilder()` and setting credentials and project id.
3. Instantiating Bean BigQueryTemplate using the BigQuery bean created in step 2.

`spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies` `3.4.0` version is used.

The application executing in VM (non-gcp env).

Another option I tried is adding below properties

1. spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.dataset-name=`datasetname`
2. spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.credentials.location=`file:/path/to/json`
3. spring.cloud.gcp.bigquery.project-id=`project-id`

I'm getting below error

```
com.google.cloud.spring.bigquery.core.BigQueryTemplate,
applog.mthd=lambda$writeJsonStream$0,
applog.line=299, applog.msg=Error: 
The Application Default Credentials are not available. 
They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. 
Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

Please let me know if I have missed any thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you followed any documentation regarding the steps you provided above?

Comment: @PoalaAstrid, No, I couldn't find any documentation. I tried after going through framework code.